# Construct a partition of unity in the centralizer of a von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $\varphi$ is a faithful normal state on $M$. Suppose that $M_{\varphi}$ is a type II$_1$ factor.

Suppose that if $p, q$ are two nonzero projections in $M_{\varphi}$, we can find $v\in M$ such that $vv^*=p, v^*v=q$ and $v\varphi=\frac{\varphi(p)}{\varphi(q)}\varphi v$.

If $\lambda\geq 1$, choose $n\geq 1$ such that $\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{\lambda}$. Then we can find a partition of unity $q_1,\cdots,q_n$ in $M_{\varphi}$ and some projections $p_1,\cdots, p_n$(not necessarily orthogonal) such that $\lambda^{-1}\varphi(p_k)=\varphi(q_k)$.

How to construct $p_i$ and $q_i(i=1,\cdots,n)$? If $q_1+q_2+\cdots q_n=1$, why does there exist some projections $p_1,\cdots, p_n$(not necessarily orthogonal) such that $\lambda^{-1}\varphi(p_k)=\varphi(q_k)$?

I tried to  construct $q_i$ in the following way: choose $0\leq a\in M_{\varphi}$ and let $B_1\cup B_2\cdots \cup B_n=\sigma(a)$.Set $q_i=1_{B_i}(a)$, then $q_1+q_2+\cdots q_n=1$. But I don't know how to construct each $p_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in your third paragraph, the problem may have no solution. For example take $n=\lambda=2$, and $q$ a projection with $\varphi(q)=\frac23$. Then the equality $\varphi(p)=\lambda\varphi(q)$ gives $\varphi(p)=\frac43$, which is impossible.

If one gets to choose both the $q$ and the $p$, then you can do the following.
Since $\varphi$ is faithful and normal and $M_\varphi$ is a II$_1$-factor, given any projection $q$ and $0\leq t\leq \varphi(q)$, there exists $p\leq q$ with $\varphi(p)=t$.

Fix $m\in\mathbb N$ with $m\geq\lambda$ and let $q_1,\ldots,q_m$ be pairwise orthogonal projections with $q_1+\cdots+q_m=1$ and $\varphi(q_j)=\frac1m$. For all $j$.

Fix $q_j$. We have $\varphi(1-q_j)=1-\frac1m$. Since $$\frac{\lambda-1}m\leq\frac{m-1}m=1-\frac1m$$
there exists a projection $r_j\leq 1-q_j$ with $\varphi(r_j)=\frac{\lambda-1}m$. Then $p_j=q_j+r_j$ is a projection and
$$
\varphi(p_j)=\varphi(q_j)+\varphi(r_j)=\frac1m+\frac{\lambda-1}m=\frac\lambda m=\lambda\,\varphi(q_j). 
$$

Comment: What is the concrete form of the each $q_i$? Can we use the spectral theorem to construct them?

Comment: Not really sure what you expect. To use the spectral theorem you would need some normal operator to start with, which I don't know where you would get from. Also, what do you mean by "construct"? Are you asking why von Neumann algebras have projections? Are you asking about the definition of "diffuse"?

Comment: I mean why can we assume that $\varphi(q_j)=\frac{1}{m}$ and $q_1+q_2+\cdots q_m=1$?

Comment: Take $q_1$ with $\varphi(q_1)=\frac1m$.  Now $1-q_1$ is a projection with $\varphi(1-q_1)=1-\frac1m$. Take a subprojection $q_2$ with $\varphi(q_2)=\frac1m$. Repeat $m$ times.